# Query to Find maximum possible combinations between two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

The target is to **create all possible combinations of joining the two columns**. every article of the first column ('100','101','102','103') must be in the combination result.

**Sample Code**

```
create table basis
(article Integer,
supplier VarChar(10) );
Insert into basis Values (100, 'A');
Insert into basis Values (101, 'A');
Insert into basis Values (101, 'B');
Insert into basis Values (101, 'C');
Insert into basis Values (102, 'D');
Insert into basis Values (103, 'B');
```

**Result set**

```
combination_nr;article;supplier
1;100;'A'
1;101;'A'
1;102;'D'
1;103;'B'
2;100;'A'
2;101;'B'
2;102;'D'
2;103;'B'
3;100;'A'
3;101;'C'
3;102;'D'
3;103;'B'
```

Let suppose **if we add one more row against 102 as 'A'** then our result set will be like this

Also according to the below-given calculations now we have 24 result sets

```
1;100;'A'
1;101;'A'
1;102;'A'
1;103;'B'

2;100;'A'
2;101;'A'
2;102;'D'
2;103;'B'

3;100;'A'
3;101;'B'
3;102;'A'
3;103;'B'

4;100;'A'
4;101;'B'
4;102;'D'
4;103;'B'

5;100;'A'
5;101;'C'
5;102;'A'
5;103;'B'

6;100;'A'
6;101;'C'
6;102;'D'
6;103;'B'
```

**Already tried code**

I have tried different ***Cross Joins*** but they always give exceeded rows according to my result sets.

```
SELECT article, supplier
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT supplier  FROM basis2) AS t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT article FROM basis2) AS t2;
```

**Calculations:**

```
article 100: 1 supplier ('A')
article 101: 3 suppliers ('A','B','C')
article 102: 1 supplier ('D')
article 103: 1 supplier ('B')
unique articles: 4 (100,101,102,103)
1x3x1x1 x 4 = 12 (combination rows)
```

Comment: The sample table data and result data are different. The table data has articles from 4711 to 4713, while the result data is from 101 to 103. We need these to line up better to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry wait a minute I will change the sample data

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn you can check now as I am having different datasets that's why I have uploaded the wrong sample.
Please if you can check now!

Comment: What do you mean by "exceeded rows"?

Comment: Do you understand what a Cartesian Product is, right?

Comment: exceeded rows means that I want 12 rows as you can see in my result sets.. but cross join gives me 16 rows more combinations than I wanted.

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you're trying to do. But to be sure, I need you to show your sample results if you add one more row with a `102` article.

Comment: yes I know cartesian product

Comment: If one more row is going to be added in `102` then my result sets will be `24`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want using a recursive CTE.  It is easier to put the combinations in single rows rather than across multiple rows:

```
with b as (
      select b.*, dense_rank() over (order by article) as seqnum
      from basis b
     ),
     cte as (
      select convert(varchar(max), concat(article, ':', supplier)) as suppliers, seqnum
      from b
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select concat(cte.suppliers, ',', concat(article, ':', supplier)), b.seqnum
      from cte join
           b
           on b.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )

select row_number() over (order by suppliers), suppliers
from (select cte.*, max(seqnum) over () as max_seqnum
      from cte
     ) cte
where seqnum = max_seqnum;
```

For your particular result set, you can unroll the string:

```
with b as (
      select b.*, dense_rank() over (order by article) as seqnum
      from basis b
     ),
     cte as (
      select convert(varchar(max), concat(article, ':', supplier)) as suppliers, seqnum
      from b
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select concat(cte.suppliers, ',', concat(article, ':', supplier)), b.seqnum
      from cte join
           b
           on b.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select seqnum, 
       left(s.value, charindex(':', s.value) - 1) as article,
       stuff(s.value, 1, charindex(s.value, ':'), '') as supplier
from (select row_number() over (order by suppliers) as seqnum, suppliers
      from (select cte.*, max(seqnum) over () as max_seqnum
            from cte
           ) cte
      where seqnum = max_seqnum
     ) cte cross apply
     string_split(suppliers, ',') s;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1bde9cde5040d9b95a70332ab9012eda) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you please help me out to solve the 100% same problem in SAP HANA SQL?

Comment: @MuhammadWaheed . . . You should ask a *new* question if you are using a different database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65528059/sap-hana-sql-query-to-find-all-possible-combinations-between-two-columns