# SAP HANA SQL Query to find all possible combinations between two columns

Tags: sql, database, hana

The target is to create all possible combinations of joining the two columns using **SAP HANA SQL**. every article of the first column ('100','101','102','103') must be in the combination result.

**Sample Code**

```
create table basis
(article Integer,
supplier VarChar(10) );
Insert into basis Values (100, 'A');
Insert into basis Values (101, 'A');
Insert into basis Values (101, 'B');
Insert into basis Values (101, 'C');
Insert into basis Values (102, 'D');
Insert into basis Values (103, 'B');
```

**Result set**

```
combination_nr;article;supplier
1;100;'A'
1;101;'A'
1;102;'D'
1;103;'B'
2;100;'A'
2;101;'B'
2;102;'D'
2;103;'B'
3;100;'A'
3;101;'C'
3;102;'D'
3;103;'B'
```

Let suppose if we add one more row against **102 as 'A'** then our result set will be like this

Also according to the below-given calculations now we have 24 result sets

```
1;100;'A'
1;101;'A'
1;102;'A'
1;103;'B'

2;100;'A'
2;101;'A'
2;102;'D'
2;103;'B'

3;100;'A'
3;101;'B'
3;102;'A'
3;103;'B'

4;100;'A'
4;101;'B'
4;102;'D'
4;103;'B'

5;100;'A'
5;101;'C'
5;102;'A'
5;103;'B'

6;100;'A'
6;101;'C'
6;102;'D'
6;103;'B'
```

**Calculations:**

```
article 100: 1 supplier ('A')
article 101: 3 suppliers ('A','B','C')
article 102: 1 supplier ('D')
article 103: 1 supplier ('B')
unique articles: 4 (100,101,102,103)
1x3x1x1 x 4 = 12 (combination rows)
```

Comment: What is the final case for which you need to multiply the data? Is it for display purposes or for some filtering? HANA does not like to multiply the data at execution time, also it can explode all the memory for quite few combinations with large groups per `article_id`. So maybe there's another less resource-consuming solution

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select article, 
       count(supplier) as nb_supplier,
       STRING_AGG(supplier,',') as list_suppliers
from (select distinct article, supplier from basis)
group by article
```